# VLC Crashes when attempting to open any video

Tags: video, vlc, crash, multimedia, playback

I open VLC, and then open the file as I would normally, but ever since I updated to 18.04 last week, VLC and Ubuntu's totem video player just crash on any attempt to open and play a video of any format.. I've tried a variety of different codec/renderer selections, but nothing works. I get the following error log.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Nov 13 12:26:30 luna2 gnome-panel[2896]: Unable to replace properties on 0: Error getting properties for ID
Nov 13 12:26:31 luna2 gnome-panel.desktop[2896]: libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
Nov 13 12:26:31 luna2 gnome-panel.desktop[2896]: libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
Nov 13 12:26:31 luna2 gnome-panel.desktop[2896]: libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
Nov 13 12:26:31 luna2 gnome-panel.desktop[2896]: libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
Nov 13 12:26:31 luna2 gnome-panel.desktop[2896]: libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Nov 13 12:26:31 luna2 kernel: [121377.710852] vlc[818]: segfault at 4 ip 00007fe4ce86b652 sp 00007fe4981d7d28 error 4 in i965_dri.so[7fe4cdf83000+b8d000]
```

Comment: With VLC not playing DVD in Kubuntu 23.04, the below solution still works.

Answer (score 8):

Hooray! I just solved it. I had to go to VLC Preferences, Video, switch to Xvideo (XCB) output, and then also go to Input/Decoder, switch to VDPAU Decoder..

And voila, it worked! Phew. Hope this info helps others.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Comment: Thanks, also worked for me :)